# JQuery truncate and reveal

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, substring

I'm looking to create an effect in my website, I have a container of info on the top of my page, acting as a header for this specific page. My 'header' item consists of some text and a rather large image, but the text is likely to need to be truncated to a certain number of characters. I want to be able to click a button and for it to then expand/slide to reveal the un-truncated text by expanding the text div, covering up the image

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="mytext" class="text"><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum sodales massa ac consectetur. Maecenas eu nisl vel erat pellentesque eleifend ut a est. Nullam ac lorem nisi, eu consequat nisi. In euismod porttitor adipiscing. Aenean feugiat, turpis nec accumsan posuere, diam tellus pharetra arcu, sit amet ultrices magna felis ac elit. Donec sit amet massa nisi, sed semper turpis. Aliquam fringilla vestibulum urna, in tincidunt dui facilisis condimentum. Integer eget enim lectus, id congue ipsum. Sed sit amet ante nec turpis mattis venenatis. In urna quam, cursus vel cursus eu, volutpat eget leo. Praesent in mi diam, vitae tincidunt eros. Etiam feugiat venenatis purus eu cursus. Curabitur euismod, dolor in rhoncus vehicula, leo justo commodo orci, id pulvinar felis purus at lacus. <a href="#" id="expand-div">Expand</a></div>
    <div class="image">Image goes here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    position:relative;
}

.image {
    background:#00b3f0;
    line-height:300px;
    color:black;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
}

.text {
    color:black;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    background:#00DD99;
    max-width:50%;
}

.text a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background:white;
    color:black;
    padding:2px 5px;
}
```

JQuery

```
var expand_btn = document.getElementById('expand-div').outerHTML;

var long_title = document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML;
var short_title = jQuery.trim(long_title).substring(0, 240).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") ;

document.getElementById('mytext').innerHTML = short_title + ' - ' +expand_btn;

$("#expand-div").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    text_div = $(this).closest('div');
    div_width = parseInt(text_div.css('max-width'));
    if(div_width == 50) {
        $(this).closest('div').animate({"max-width": "100%"}, "slow");
        document.getElementById('expand-div').innerHTML = 'Shrink';
    } else {
        $(this).closest('div').animate({"max-width": "50%"}, "slow");
        document.getElementById('expand-div').innerHTML = 'Expand';
    }
});
```

[I have put together a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enkV4/1/) to show the kind of effect I was after, but I've never been the best at writing JQuery and I've probably made mistakes for myself when I tried to change between the texts because it stopped working. Ideally from this position I would like to animate the truncate effect, but that isn't necessary.

Comment: Search for jquery ellipsis or use [css](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [css text-overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) property should make this a lot easier. It won't work on some older browsers, though.

Comment: Please use a higher quality site to link to, such as http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html

Comment: I'd never even heard of this property, using this I could just change the size of the container, from what I can see it seems to have quite good browser compatibility, what would happen for older browsers, would I have to fall back to regular overflow:hidden?

Comment: Excellent! made it work with a [little amending to the code](http://jsfiddle.net/enkV4/2/), but this is pretty much exactly what I was after. Thanks :)